# Scrapy: Rule SgmlLinkExtractor concept

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, scrapy

Please guide me how to write Rule SgmlLinkExtractor
I am confused and can't figure out the english documents

I want to crawl the web with many pages
And the rule is :

```
 http://abctest.com/list.php?c=&&page=1  
 http://abctest.com/list.php?c=&&page=2  
 http://abctest.com/list.php?c=&&page=3 ...
```

Here is my code:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
import re

class Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "find"
    start_urls = ["http://abctest.com/list.php?c=&&page=1",]
    #crawl 2 pages to test if the data is normal  allow=('?c=&&page=/d+')
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('?c=&&page=2')),callback='parse_item',follow=True)]


    #get the page1 item
    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.css("div#list table tr ")
        for site in sites:
            item = LAItem()
            item['day']  = site.css("  td.date::text ").extract()
            item['URL'] = site.css("  td.subject a::attr(href) ").extract()
         yield item

   #get the page2 item    
   def parse_item(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.css("div#list table tr ")
        for site in sites:
            item = LAItem()
            item['day']  = site.css("  td.date::text ").extract()
            item['URL'] = site.css("  td.subject a::attr(href) ").extract()
         yield item
```

Comment: Do you know how many pages do you have?

Comment: more than 10,but I want to test just 2 pages to see if the data is nornal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a `LinkExtractor` and `CrawlSpider` here - just regular [`Spider`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider). What you need is to define [`start_requests()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.start_requests) method and yield requests from it:

```
from scrapy import Request, Spider
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

URL = 'http://abctest.com/list.php?c=&&page={page}'


class Spider(Spider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [404]
    name = "find"

    def start_requests(self):
        index = 1
        while True:
            yield Request(URL.format(page=index))
            index +=1

    def parse(self, response):
        if response.status == 404:
            raise CloseSpider("Met the page which doesn't exist")

        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.css("div#list table tr ")
        for site in sites:
            item = LAItem()
            item['day']  = site.css("  td.date::text ").extract()
            item['URL'] = site.css("  td.subject a::attr(href) ").extract()
         yield item
```

Note that the trick here is to continue getting the pages until we meet the first response with 404 - Page not found. This should make it work for any number of pages.

Comment: What if I only want to test 2 pages? I use 
            index +=1
            if index ==6 :
                raise CloseSpider("Met the page which doesn't exist") It works but have a ERROR:Obtaining request from start requests

Comment: just put `break` into the while loop if `index` hits the value `6`: `if index == 6: break`.